# Create a new ROS Android package - error rosmake

Tags: ros, android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a new ROS Android package - [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20ROS%20Android%20project)

```
petinv@ubuntu2:~/ros_work_electric$ rosmake vp_android1
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['vp_android1']                                                                                                   
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/petinv/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121010-220938                                                              
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['vp_android1'] to:
['vp_android1']                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages vp_android1.  This may take a few seconds.                                                       
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> vp_android1 [ make ]                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] All 2 linesvp_android1: 0.2 sec ]                                                                                [ 1 Active 0/1 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  **Makefile:1: /home/petinv/ros_work_electric/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/rosjava.mk: Нет такого файла или каталога**
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package vp_android1 written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/petinv/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121010-220938/vp_android1/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< vp_android1 [FAIL] [ 0.19 seconds ]                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package vp_android1. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                        
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                  
**[ rosmake ] Built 1 packages with 1 failures.**                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] /home/petinv/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121010-220938
```

file rosjava.mk not exist.

I remove and install rosjava and android_core,
but nothing has changed
?????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45538/create-a-new-ros-android-package---error-rosmake/) by [victor.petin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3359/victor.petin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That tutorial is outdated and refers to the rosjava version before rosjava switched to the gradle build system. Rosmake is not supported any more.

Either use the last working version of rosjava before the switch to gradle:

```
hg clone -r 1084ec6c569c 'https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/' 'rosjava_core'
```

... or (better) use the new documentation [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-11-13**:
I've deleted the offending wiki page.